# Делаю игру крестики нолики без методов. Как мне в данном коде лучше проверить занято поле или нет? И если занято просить вводить новое значение?

Tags: java

```
package homeWork.homeWork3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = 3;
        int heigth = length;
        int[][] array = new int[length][heigth];
        String[][] oXArray = new String[length][heigth];
        int[] closeArray = new int[9];
        int count = 1;
        int close = 0;
        boolean game = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                oXArray[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
        while (game) {
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + array[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("Select field");
            System.out.print("Turn x : ");
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            closeArray[close] = x;
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    if (x == array[i][j]) {
                        oXArray[i][j] = "X";
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + oXArray[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
                if ((oXArray[p][0] == "X" && oXArray[p][1] == "X" && oXArray[p][2] == "X") ||
                        (oXArray[0][p] == "X" && oXArray[1][p] == "X" && oXArray[2][p] == "X")) {
                    System.out.println("X is winner");
                    game = false;
                    break;
                } else if ((oXArray[0][0] == "X" && oXArray[1][1] == "X" && oXArray[2][2] == "X") ||
                        (oXArray[2][0] == "X" && oXArray[1][1] == "X" && oXArray[0][2] == "X")) {
                    System.out.println("X is winner");
                    game = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (close == 9) {
                System.out.println("Draw");
                game = false;
            }
            if (game == false) {
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + array[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println("Select field");
                System.out.print("Turn o : ");
                int o = sc.nextInt();
                closeArray[close] = o;
                close++;
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        if (o == array[i][j]) {
                            oXArray[i][j] = "O";
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + oXArray[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
                    if ((oXArray[p][0] == "O" && oXArray[p][1] == "O" && oXArray[p][2] == "O") ||
                            (oXArray[0][p] == "O" && oXArray[1][p] == "O" && oXArray[2][p] == "O")) {
                        System.out.println("O is winner");
                        game = false;
                        break;
                    } else if ((oXArray[0][0] == "O" && oXArray[1][1] == "O" && oXArray[2][2] == "O") ||
                            (oXArray[2][0] == "O" && oXArray[1][1] == "O" && oXArray[0][2] == "O")) {
                        System.out.println("O is winner");
                        game = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Game is over");
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделать программу согласно принципам ООП и тогда таких вопрос не будет.

Answer (score 2):

в вашем коде разбираться нет смысла и желания. если вы хотите писать "без методов", то стоит вернуться к бейсику. попробуйте немного отрефакторить этот код, это лучше, чем писать "без методов"...

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Field field = new Field();
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int moveCount = 0;

        while (true) {

            out.println("Select field");
            out.println("Turn " + field.getValue() + " : ");

            if (field.nextMove(sc.nextLine())) {
                out.println(field);
                moveCount++;
            } 
            else out.println("Incorrect input! Try again...");

            String win = field.getWin();
            if (win != null) {
                System.out.println(win + " win!");
                break;
            }

            if (moveCount >= 9) break;

        }
        out.println("Game over!");
    }

}

import java.util.Objects;

public class Field {

    private final Boolean [][] FIELD;
    private boolean turnToWalk;

    public Field() {
        this.turnToWalk = true;
        this.FIELD = new Boolean[3][3];
    }

    public boolean nextMove(String userInput) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.valueOf(userInput);
            if (i < 1 || i > 9) return false;
            int x = (i - 1) / 3;
            int y = (i - 1) % 3;
            if (FIELD[x][y] != null) return false;
            FIELD[x][y] = turnToWalk;
            turnToWalk = !turnToWalk;
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String getWin(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if (equalsField (FIELD[0][i], FIELD[1][i], FIELD[2][i])) return getValue(!turnToWalk);
            if (equalsField (FIELD[i][0], FIELD[i][1], FIELD[i][2])) return getValue(!turnToWalk);            
        } 
        if (equalsField (FIELD[0][0], FIELD[1][1], FIELD[2][2])) return getValue(!turnToWalk);
        if (equalsField (FIELD[0][2], FIELD[1][1], FIELD[2][0])) return getValue(!turnToWalk);
        return null;
    }
    private boolean equalsField(Boolean f1, Boolean f2, Boolean f3){
        return (f1==null||f2==null||f3==null) ? 
                false : Objects.equals(f1, f2) && Objects.equals(f1, f3);
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return getValue(turnToWalk);
    }

    private String getValue(Boolean value){
        if (value==null) return "-";
        else return value==true ? "X" : "O";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < FIELD.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FIELD[i].length; j++) {
                sb.append(getValue(FIELD[i][j]));
            }
            sb.append("\r\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет. Просто задачей ставил написать именно без методов

Answer (score 0):

```
package homeWork.homeWork3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = 3;
        int heigth = length;
        int[][] array = new int[length][heigth];
        String[][] oXArray = new String[length][heigth];
        int[] closeArray = new int[9];
        int count = 1;
        int close = 0;
        boolean game = true;
        boolean place = true;
        int x = 0;
        int o = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                array[i][j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                oXArray[i][j] = "-";
            }
        }
        while (game) {
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + array[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            while (place) {
                System.out.println("Select field");
                System.out.print("Turn x : ");
                x = sc.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    if (closeArray[i] == x || x > 9) {
                        place = true;
                        System.out.println("Invalid field.");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        place = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            place = true;
            closeArray[close] = x;
            close++;
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    if (x == array[i][j]) {
                        oXArray[i][j] = "X";
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + oXArray[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
                if ((oXArray[p][0] == "X" && oXArray[p][1] == "X" && oXArray[p][2] == "X") ||
                        (oXArray[0][p] == "X" && oXArray[1][p] == "X" && oXArray[2][p] == "X")) {
                    System.out.println("X is winner");
                    game = false;
                    break;
                } else if ((oXArray[0][0] == "X" && oXArray[1][1] == "X" && oXArray[2][2] == "X") ||
                        (oXArray[2][0] == "X" && oXArray[1][1] == "X" && oXArray[0][2] == "X")) {
                    System.out.println("X is winner");
                    game = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (close == 9) {
                System.out.println("Draw");
                game = false;
            }
            if (game == false) {
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + array[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                while (place) {
                    System.out.println("Select field");
                    System.out.print("Turn o : ");
                    o = sc.nextInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                        if (closeArray[i] == o || o > 9) {
                            place = true;
                            System.out.println("Invalid field.");
                            break;
                        } else {
                            place = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                place = true;
                closeArray[close] = o;
                close++;
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        if (o == array[i][j]) {
                            oXArray[i][j] = "O";
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < heigth; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + oXArray[i][j]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                for (int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
                    if ((oXArray[p][0] == "O" && oXArray[p][1] == "O" && oXArray[p][2] == "O") ||
                            (oXArray[0][p] == "O" && oXArray[1][p] == "O" && oXArray[2][p] == "O")) {
                        System.out.println("O is winner");
                        game = false;
                        break;
                    } else if ((oXArray[0][0] == "O" && oXArray[1][1] == "O" && oXArray[2][2] == "O") ||
                            (oXArray[2][0] == "O" && oXArray[1][1] == "O" && oXArray[0][2] == "O")) {
                        System.out.println("O is winner");
                        game = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Game is over");
    }
}
```